# Gridview in android home screen widget

Tags: android

I want to add Straggered GridView in my home screen widget (Like Google Keep). I have used Straggered GridView in my app.
I can't figure out a way to do this. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

refer this you will get all idea

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget

NOTE : They have used listview you can replace it with your gridview and try

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following tutorial.

http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-part-6-staggered-gridview/

And this:-

https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo

Both have a good tutorial on StaggeredGridView

Comment: i know how to implement SGV in activity, I just want to know the way to do it in home screen widget. Thanks for the help anyways

Comment: Please read the question before asking, he asks about the widget not home screen